# Share HttpContext between WCF Service and MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I had created a project with MVC 5 and WCF.I had a WCF Service with **AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed** and also in web.config

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

In MVC Controller i am adding value to session

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        ServiceReference1.MyService2Client ur = new ServiceReference1.MyService2Client();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Add("UserId", 1);
            ViewBag.msg = ur.Test();

            return View();
        }
}
```

In WCF Service :

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
       = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MyService2 : IMyService2
    {
        private Test _test;
        public MyService2(Test test)
        {
            _test = test;
        }

        public string Test()
        {
            var test = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]; // Its Coming as NULL
            return "Serivce Success";
        }
    }
```

Even though i am adding session variable in MVC Controller and try to access the session variable in WCF Service, the session variable is not present when request comes to WCF Service.

In MVC web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService2" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:30380/MyService2.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService2" contract="ServiceReference1.IMyService2"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService2" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

In WCF web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"  />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Help me out to resolve it

Comment: You are hosting the MVC site in one application with its own session, and calling a WCF service which is a different application with it's own session.   You will need to pass the data to WCF in the service call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no httpcontext in a wcf web service,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-services-and-aspnet
As the document mentioned, we use the OperationContext.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2
if you want to store the user data, you should enable the WCF session mode.
In that case, the wcf server has the ablilty to identity the client. It can be associated with all messages sent from specific clients to specific service instances.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27896125-b61e-42bd-a1b0-e6da5c23e6fc/httpcontextcurrent-in-wcf